# Sanitization html output itself

Tags: sanitization, coding-standards

I've just started code according to VIP WordPress Coding Standards and I stuck with sanitization. I know that all outputs need sanitization without any exception. But how can I do sanitization of a function which has HTML code output itself? Eg. function yoast_breadcrumb() from Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin which outputs HTML formatted breadcumb..?

```
<?php echo yoast_breadcrumb( '', '', false ); ?>
```

Output:

```
<span prefix="v: http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="https://rnc-wordpress-wrongware.c9.io" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Main Page</a></span> › <span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><span class="breadcrumb_last" property="v:title">Page doesn't exist</span></span></span>
```

Comment: You don't. `yoast_breadcrumb()` is already sanitizing by itself.

Comment: I know that it's. But please read VIP WP standards, you have to sanitize everything. Here is good explanation - https://vip.wordpress.com/2014/06/20/the-importance-of-escaping-all-the-things/

Comment: Check out [`wp_kses()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) for sanitizing HTML.

Comment: So do I need every single function check for output, find out which html tags are used and write them all to the wp_kses function ok? It's so much work.

Comment: I would just allow `span` and `a` with the attributes `typeof`, `href`, `rel`, `property` and `class`.

Comment: Of course, but there can be much more crazy output with tons of HTML tags and it could be make me insane..

Comment: Agreed, but unlikely. There is no shortcut or win-win. If you want to strictly adhere to VIP coding standards, you need to put the work in - and accept there will always (potentially) be a consequence of aggressive sanitization.

Comment: Just for the sake of interest, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28588560/1908141) about sanitation

Answer (score 0):

The more elaborate data is, the harder it is to both *formulate* and *implement* sanitization process.

For a number this might be as simple as "integer" and `(int)$number`.

For HTML this is highly not trivial with different possibilities of desired scope (no HTML tags? some blacklisted tags? some whitelisted tags? what about embedded scripts? CSS?) and *very* challenging implementation.

While WP does have [`wp_kses()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_kses/) implementing sanitization of HTML, it's relatively slow and its reputation is less than stellar (or so I read in context of other established sanitization libraries).

I would say that in question as stated, the *practical* expectation is that function engineered to act as template tag is *expected* to produce sanitized output.

If you don't *believe* it to, it would probably make more sense to audit it (and report any discovered shortcomings to developer) rather than try to sanitize complex output.